# Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute error

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

what is wrong with my code? i dont know why is it calling an erro

```
'lbladmission = tk.Label(window, text = "ADMISSION SYSTEM", bg = "grey", width = "300", height = "2", font = ("Times New Roman", 12)).pack()
lbladmission.grid(row=0, column=1)'
```

i always get this error

```
'File "d:/PYTHON/login_form.py", line 78, in login_form
lbladmission.place(height=2)
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'place''

Comment: Why did you use `.gird()` after you have used `.pack()`?

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 0):

The tkinter .pack() method returns None. Use:

```
lbladmission = tk.Label(windo ...
lbladmission.pack()
```